# what is the main use of set home value in windows registry?

Tags: oracle, registry

in windows registry there are keys for each application, for oracle i could see two home values each for oracle 9i & 10g, what DB home value would be eventually used during DB access by external application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whatever connection is present will be used by the PC according to tnsnames.ora file content.